# SoapClient getFunctions how to use the output provided

Tags: php, soap

I am new to SoapClient, now I'm making a soap request with the following code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/webservices/venues.asmx?wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
```

Then I am calling the SoapClient `__getFunctions` function and printing out the data. Below is the response I get:

```
GetVenueResponse GetVenue(GetVenueRequest $getVenueRequest)
```

However, how do I use this output to make a soap client call in order to gain a response from passing data such as in id with a value of "test123"?

Also if i do __getTypes(), I get the following output:

```
[0]=>
  string(43) "struct GetVenueRequest {
 string VenueId;
}"
```

**EDIT:**
I have tried to do the following from the data above:

```
class GetVenueRequest {
  function GetVenueRequest($id) 
  {
      $this->VenueId = $id;
  }
}
$getVenueRequest = new GetVenueRequest("TEST123");
$params = array(
   "GetVenueRequest" => $getVenueRequest,
 );

$response = $client->__soapCall("GetVenue", array($params));
```

But I end up with the following error message:

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
```